# How to get the intercepts from LASSO Regressions run in R using the enet function from the elasticnet package

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, feature-selection, montecarlo

All of the scripts and datasets (plus the file folder containing those datasets) for running the following code snippets can be found in my [Github Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/Estimated-Exhaustive-Regression-Project) for this project.

So, as part of this collaborative research project which proposes a novel statistical/machine learning procedure/algorithm for obtaining optimal features/variables in a regression model, we are comparing it on the same file folder full of randomly generated synthetic datasets against 2 or 3 Benchmark Methods (LASSO, BE Stepwise, & FS Stepwise), i.e. a Monte Carlo Simulation based Comparison, and I have already run all three Benchmark methods (with the same random seeds) in RStudio, but the enet() function I used from the elasticnet package in R is not returning the coefficient estimates for the intercepts on each of the fitted LASSO Regressions (the other two are already fortunately).

The following code I used to run my LASSO Regressions is all contained in the "LASSO code.R" and "LASSO code (2).R" scripts in my aforementioned [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/Estimated-Exhaustive-Regression-Project) for this project:

```
# load all necessary packages using only 1 command/line
library_list1 <- c(library(stats),library(dplyr),library(tidyverse),
                  library(readr),library(stringi)) 
library_list2 <- c(library(stats), library(leaps),
                   library(lars), library(elasticnet))

# these 2 lines together create a simple character list of 
# all the file names in the file folder of datasets you created
directory_path <- "~/DAEN_698/sample obs"
filepath_list <- list.files(path = directory_path, full.names = TRUE, 
                        recursive = TRUE)

datasets <- lapply(list.files(path = "~/DAEN_698/sample obs", 
                              full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE), 
                   read.csv)

# reformat the names of each of the csv file formatted dataset
DS_names_list <- basename(filepath_list)
DS_names_list <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(DS_names_list)

set.seed(11)     # to ensure replicability
LASSO_fits <- lapply(datasets, function(i) 
           enet(x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), 
           y = i$Y, lambda = 0, normalize = FALSE))


# This stores and prints out all of the regression 
# equation specifications selected by LASSO when called
set.seed(11)     # to ensure replicability
LASSO_Coeffs <- lapply(LASSO_fits, 
                   function(i) predict(i, x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), 
                                       s = 0.1, mode = "fraction", 
                                       type = "coefficients")[["coefficients"]])

positive_coeffs <- lapply(LASSO_Coeffs, function(i) i[i > 0])

IVs_selected_by_LASSO <- lapply(LASSO_Coeffs, function(i) names(i[i > 0]))
```

And the problem is that after I run the above two lines, then I run head(positive_coeffs) and head(IVs_selected_by_LASSO), I get neither the coefficient estimates or even the inclusion of (intercept) at the start of every line of the IVs_selected_by_LASSO object and I need both. This is what I actually get:

```
> positive_coeffs[1]
[[1]]
       X2         X3 
0.08618449 0.24170494 
> positive_coeffs[[1]]
        X2         X3 
0.08618449 0.24170494 
> IVs_selected_by_LASSO[1]
[[1]]
[1] "X2" "X3"
> IVs_selected_by_LASSO[[1]]
[1] "X2" "X3"
```

But the output I actually need would be the following instead:

```
> positive_coeffs[1]
[[1]]
       X2         X3 
0.555555555 0.08618449 0.24170494 
> positive_coeffs[[1]] 
(intercept)        X2         X3 
0.555555555 0.08618449 0.24170494 
> IVs_selected_by_LASSO[[1]]
[1] (intercept) "X2" "X3
```

p.s. I also get no coefficient estimates when I try the following which works for my BE Stepwise Regression:

```
> head(LASSO_fits, n = 1)
[[1]]
Call:
enet(x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), y = i$Y, 
lambda = 0, normalize = FALSE)
```

(the rest of it is way too much to include here, and it's all irrelevant anyway)

```
> summary(LASSO_fits[1])
 Length Class Mode
[1,] 14     enet  list

> coefficients((LASSO_fits[[1]]))
NULL
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to find the intercept in LASSO_Coeffs[[1]] as it is just a named vector. Only the coeffecients are selected while making the `LASSO_Coeffs` object, so it is pointless to try searching for them afterwards. You need to show the exact code (with minimal explanation) producing your expected output for one csv, which is unclear right now.

Comment: So where does the 0.5555 come from? Where is it stored in the enet? What file is this for? In code, how do we extract the intercept for just one csv? Please @ me in the comments when you make edits so I can see.

Comment: @dcsuka
Sorry, I should have put a comment above or next to that line, I just put a placeholder decimal value in there and made it all 5s so that would be obvious.

Comment: Which csv file in the folder you sent me is this? I need to know exactly where the intercept comes from in the model structure so I can concatenate it.

Comment: @dcsuka okay, I just completed what you asked for and I think I emailed it and the 1st dataset on which it all runs to you, but if not, they are both on my GitHub repository "Estimated-Exhaustive-Regression-Project", they are called 'LASSO code (2) (manual run on a singe csv)' and '0.4-3-1-1' respectively.

Comment: Ok, I am looking at '0.4-3-1-1', and I get X2 and X3. Where is the intercept in the class structure of enet? Does enet even compute the intercept? Do you know the value, and how to access it? If so, the rest is easy. Based on the documentation of enet https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/elasticnet/versions/1.3/topics/enet it appears that by default intercept is True, so the coefficients are centered around the intercept.

Comment: If you toggle intercept between True and False, you will find that the coefficients change value.

Comment: @dcsuka their estimated coefficients should change value for every fitted LASSO, but there is one thing I need to clarify in your response still. When you say the coefficients change value when toggling between True and False, they still all include the intercepts with a corresponding coefficient estimate, right?

Comment: Try experimenting with toggling intercept to True and False in the enet function, and observe the change in coefficient estimates. Not sure what you mean by nclude the intercepts with a corresponding coefficient estimate. All the intercepts? Shouldnt there be one per lasso?

Comment: Yes, there should only be one intercept per LASSO, what I meant was all of the intercepts because there are i individual LASSO fits. As for the intercepts, how about this, what if I use lapply(cbind(1, LASSO_Coeffs)), could something like that work?

Comment: do you know where within an enet object the lasso coefficient is? that needs to be established first.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might look something like this:

```r
LASSO_Coeffs <- lapply(LASSO_fits, 
                   function(i) {predictions <- predict(i, x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), 
                                       s = 0.1, mode = "fraction", 
                                       type = "coefficients")
                   c(predictions$fraction, predictions$coefficients)})
```

If `predictions$fraction` is the intercept, you concatenate it with the coefficients.